# Cannot install ionic with npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ionic-framework

I want to install ionic with "npm install -g ionic" but i have this message :

npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-39-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm v3.3.5

npm ERR! Object # has no method 'exists'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/linux-sysalia6/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1

I work with ubuntu 
thx!

Comment: which version of node are you running? (You can check with `node --version`)

Comment: node : v0.6.12  npm : v3.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your node installation.
`v0.6.12` is quite old and is missing the `fs.exists` function needed by npm.

You can update node on Ubuntu using these commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```